# Establishing a TCP connection with python(Already accomplished in C# I need help converting it)

Tags: c#, python, sockets

I already have this c# written that can connect to my server

```
TcpClient Connector = new TcpClient();

                //If you can't connect, it takes you back here to try again.

                GetConnection:

            //Get the user to enter the IP of the server.

            Console.WriteLine("Enter server IP :");

            string IP = Console.ReadLine();

            //Attempt to connect; use a try...catch statement to avoid crashes.

            try
            {

                //Connect to the specified IP on port 2000

                Connector.Connect(IP, 2000);

                //So the program continues to receive commands.

                IsConnected = true;


                //Make Writer the stream coming from / going to Connector.

                Writer = Connector.GetStream();

                //We connected!

            }

            catch
            {

                //We couldn't connect :-(

                Console.WriteLine("Error connecting to target server! Press any key to try again.");

                Console.ReadKey();

                //Go back and start again!

                Console.Clear();

                goto GetConnection;

            }
```

What my problem is, is trying to convert it to python.  Here's what I wrote in python

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    ip = raw_input('Enter IP of vicitm: ')
    print ip
    import socket               
    s = socket.socket()         
    port = 2000                
    s.connect((ip, port))
    print s.recv(1024)
    s.close
```

It appears I can not connect but I don't know why.  Can anyone explain it to me?  Also if there's a better way to do it in python I'd love to hear it!  Thank you in advance!

Comment: There's not anything wrong with your code. Why do you think that this is not working?  Is there an error message or an exception being raised? Try to describe the problem that you are experiencing. Why do you think it can not connect?

Comment: The line print s.recv(1024) wasn't producing anything which made me think it wasn't working

Comment: So it's blocked waiting for the server to send it's data... up to 1024 bytes. There will be buffering going on, and the data might not be made available to your client. You could use `select.select()` to test whether your socket has data to be read.